# Java - GUI won't run after compiling

Tags: java, user-interface

I've done a few  other simple GUI projects the past few weeks, without much of any problem but now I am having trouble getting the program to show after compiling.  I can't figure out what might be wrong as there are no errors being thrown and it is in pretty much the same format as other projects I was given for school.

Any guidance on where to look to get the GUI on screen would be appreciated so that I may go through and tweek things I want before I turn this in.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/***********************************************************************
Program Name: ProgramName.java
Programmer's Name: Student Name
Program Description: Describe here what this program will do
***********************************************************************/
public class GuessGame extends JFrame{

    //Declare GUI components
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JButton guessButton;
    private JButton exitButton;
    private JTextField guessField;
    private JTextField answerField;
    private JLabel directionsLabel;
    private JLabel guessLabel;
    private JLabel answerLabel;



    public GuessGame(){

        //Initialize window components
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Number Guessing Game");
        exitButton =  new JButton("Exit");
        guessButton = new JButton("Try your luck");
        guessField = new JTextField(4);
        answerField = new JTextField(50);
        guessLabel = new JLabel("What is your guess?");
        answerLabel = new JLabel("Now it is/isn't");
        directionsLabel = new JLabel("Enter a number and then press the" +
                "guess button until you are correct");

        //Build the GUI
        Container c = mainFrame.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        c.add(directionsLabel);
        c.add(guessLabel);
        c.add(guessField);
        c.add(answerLabel);
        c.add(answerField);
        c.add(guessButton);
        c.add(exitButton);

        //Set Mnemonics
        guessButton.setMnemonic('G');
        exitButton.setMnemonic('E');

        mainFrame.setSize(450, 300);

        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        //Call the handler methods for specific functions
        GuessButtonHandler ghandler = new GuessButtonHandler();
        guessButton.addActionListener(ghandler);

        ExitButtonHandler ehandler = new ExitButtonHandler();
        exitButton.addActionListener(ehandler);

        FocusHandler fhandler = new FocusHandler();
        guessField.addFocusListener(fhandler);
        answerField.addFocusListener(fhandler);

    }

    //Implement actionListener for the Guess button
    class GuessButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String instring;
            int counter = 0;
            int guess;
            Random rand = new Random();
            int numberToGuess = rand.nextInt(1000);

            instring = guessField.getText();

            guess = Integer.parseInt(instring);
            counter++;

            if (guess == numberToGuess){
                answerLabel = new JLabel("You win! " + 
        "\nThe number was: " + numberToGuess + 
                "\nIt took you " + counter + " tries");
            }
            else if (guess < numberToGuess){
                answerLabel = new JLabel("Too low");
            }
            else if (guess > numberToGuess){
                answerLabel = new JLabel("Too high");
            }           
        }
    }

    //Implement ActionListener for the exit button
    class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    //Implement focus listener
    class FocusHandler implements FocusListener{
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
            if (e.getSource()== guessField){
                answerField.setText("");
            }
            else if (e.getSource() == answerField){
                guessButton.requestFocus();
            }
        }


        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {

        }
    }

    //Main to run program, call GuessGame method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GuessGame();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to call `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame after adding all components to it. The program won't mathemagically know that you want to to display anything unless you specifically tell it to do so.

i.e.,

```
public GuessGame() {

  // Initialize window components
  mainFrame = new JFrame("Number Guessing Game");

  // ..... etc....

  FocusHandler fhandler = new FocusHandler();
  guessField.addFocusListener(fhandler);
  answerField.addFocusListener(fhandler);

  mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Also, you don't want to have this class extend JFrame since this is not necessary. You are already using a JFrame in the constructor and so have no need for another JFrame in the class itself.

Comment: Knew it was something so simple.  I could have sworn it was in there, yet didn't realize it wasn't after this whole time.  Thanks a ton.  As far as the extending JFrame, was not well aware of that part.  Guess it was something I thought needed as it was with the other labs we had done despite having other JFrames in it.  I will crack it with this change, thanks a ton.

Comment: @user1174357: When I ran your code there were no errors, but it just ran and quit, and that was it, a symptom that suggested that the Swing thread was never started. That's when I knew to look for your call to `setVisible(...)`. Next we'll work on your use of layout managers so that you can eventually call `pack()` on your JFrame and get decent looking GUI's.